# Calculate indefinite integral which is sum of non-computable ones

Tags: analysis, indefinite-integrals

There is the integral:
$$\int e^{-2x}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{3}{x}\right)dx$$

The integral cannot be calculated if divide it into sum of two integrals and try to solve them one by one. But there is the way to solve it as a whole sum.

The way exists because of that example if we assume that $f(x)$ is function with non-computable integral $\int(x-f(x))dx$ is non-computable too. But $\int f(x)dx + \int (x-f(x))dx$ can be calculated.

Comment: Are you trying to find the antiderivative? Because I don't think that exists using elementary functions either. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28exp%28-2x%29%281%2Fx%5E2%2B3%2Fx%29%29

Comment: If it is $e^{-\color{red}{3}x}\left(\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{3}{x}\right)$ or $e^{-2x}\left(\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{\color{red}{2}}{x}\right)$, there are elementary antiderivative. For the one you have, I fear there isn't one.

Comment: Well, you could show us your progress if you emphatically say that: “there is the way to solve it as a whole sum”.

Comment: @Rohan I have no progress because all I need is transformation for this sum to be computable. And I ask only for idea of it.

Comment: FYI - "non-computable" actually means something different than what you are using it to mean here (which appears to be that you can't find an elementary antiderivative).

Answer (score 1):

$\int e^{-2x}\left(\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{3}{x}\right)~dx$

$=\int\dfrac{e^{-2x}}{x^2}~dx+\int\dfrac{3e^{-2x}}{x}~dx$

$=-\int e^{-2x}~d\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)+\int\dfrac{3e^{-2x}}{x}~dx$

$=-\dfrac{e^{-2x}}{x}+\int\dfrac{1}{x}~d\left(e^{-2x}\right)+\int\dfrac{3e^{-2x}}{x}~dx$

$=-\dfrac{e^{-2x}}{x}-\int\dfrac{2e^{-2x}}{x}~dx+\int\dfrac{3e^{-2x}}{x}~dx$

$=-\dfrac{e^{-2x}}{x}+\int\dfrac{e^{-2x}}{x}~dx$

$=-\dfrac{e^{-2x}}{x}+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n2^nx^{n-1}}{n!}~dx$

$=-\dfrac{e^{-2x}}{x}+\int\left(\dfrac{1}{x}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n2^nx^{n-1}}{n!}\right)~dx$

$=-\dfrac{e^{-2x}}{x}+\ln x+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n2^nx^n}{n!n}+C$